# Scala - duplicated hierarchy for companion object

Tags: scala, inheritance, companion-object

I'm pretty new to Scala, and I was wondering which is the best way to organize the hierarchy for classes and their companion objects.

Suppose that I have a base class or interface that I want to extend. In Python I'd do something like this:

```
class Base(object):
    def an_instance_method(self):
        return 0

    @classmethod
    def a_class_method(cls):
        return 1

    def another_instance_method(self):
        raise NotImplentedError()

    @classmethod
    def another_class_method(cls):
        raise NotImplementedError()

class A(Base):
    def another_instance_method(self):
        return self.an_instance_method() + 1

    @classmethod
    def another_class_method(cls):
        return cls.a_class_method() + 1

class B(Base):
    def another_instance_method(self):
        return self.an_instance_method() + 2

    @classmethod
    def another_class_method(cls):
        return cls.a_class_method() + 2
```

My current Scala solution is the following:

```
trait Base {
  def an_instance_method(): Int = 0
  def another_instance_method(): Int
}

trait BaseCompanion {
  def a_class_method(): Int = 1
  def another_class_method(): Int
}

class A extends Base {
  override def another_instance_method(): Int = an_instance_method() + 1
}
object A extends BaseCompanion {
  override def another_class_method(): Int = a_class_method() + 1
}

class B extends Base {
  override def another_instance_method(): Int = an_instance_method() + 2
}
object B extends BaseCompanion {
  override def another_class_method(): Int = a_class_method() + 2
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: What do you find wrong with your proposed approach?

Comment: It just seems a bit redundant, so I was wondering if there's some other practice or if there's at least some common naming convention as I don't like naming the corresponding "companion trait" with the "Companion" suffix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example in Shapeless you can find traits

- `ProductTypeClass` and `ProductTypeClassCompanion`,
- `LabelledProductTypeClass` and `LabelledProductTypeClassCompanion`.

https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/shapeless/typeclass.scala

So I guess naming and organizing hierarchies are ok although you don't provide details how you use connection between class A and object A, class B and object B. Now they seem to be independent so an object A now can be not necessarily the companion object of class A and just some object A1.

Actually I don't think this is redundant since these two hierarchies are two different ones. Class A and its companion object A are completely different and not connected in sense of inheritance and typing ([Class companion object vs. case class itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75286750/class-companion-object-vs-case-class-itself)), the only specific is that they can see members of each other.