# Scala classOf vs getClass with Case class

Tags: scala, class, object

Can someone please explain the difference between `classOf[DataModel]` and `DataModel.getClass()`?

Here `DataModel` is a **case** class.

Comment: Well, one is a function that you can call given a type, and the other is a method that you can call given a value. - Note, if you call `DataModel.getClass` you are getting the `Class` of the _syntethic class_ of the companion object of `DataModel`, rather than the `Class` of the `DataModel` type.

Comment: Thanks, this helps. Is there any online resource you aware of about this? Tried searching but couldn't find any. :/

Comment: It depends what you mean with _"this"_, what I said can just be derived if you understand the basis of the language _(to distinguish a `class` / `trait` from its companion `object`)_, understanding the difference between types and classes, and understanding singleton types.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `DataModel` in `DataModel.getClass()` refers not to the case class `DataModel` but to its companion object

[Class companion object vs. case class itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75286750/class-companion-object-vs-case-class-itself/)

But suppose you meant `classOf[DataModel]` vs. `DataModel(...arguments...).getClass()`.

One more possible confusion here is between compile time and runtime

[Runtime vs. Compile time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/846103/runtime-vs-compile-time)

In `classOf[DataModel]` the class `DataModel` must be known at **compile time**. You're using its **type** `DataModel` in a type position `[DataModel]` in `classOf[DataModel]`. (*)

In `DataModel(...).getClass()` you're calling the method `.getClass()` on an **instance** `DataModel(...)` of the case class. So you're calling it at **runtime**

```
trait Parent
case class DataModel(/*...*/) extends Parent
// static (compile-time) type of x is Parent, dynamic (runtime) type is DataModel 
val x: Parent = DataModel(/*...*/)
x.getClass // class DataModel
```

In the latter case the class even can be not known at compile time at all, for example can be generated at runtime

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.{currentMirror => rm}
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe.Quasiquote
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
val tb = rm.mkToolBox()

val symbol = tb.define(q"case class DataModel() extends Parent")
val x: Any = tb.eval(q"new $symbol()")
x.getClass // class __wrapper....DataModel
```

(*) Well, if this is really necessary you can actually call `classOf[DataModel]` even at runtime for runtime-generated class `DataModel` by means of runtime compilation (toolbox) again (in such case you create a new compile time inside the runtime)

```
tb.eval(q"classOf[$symbol]").asInstanceOf[Class[_]] // class __wrapper....DataModel
```

You can read also about the difference between type and class

[What is the difference between Type and Class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/468145/what-is-the-difference-between-type-and-class)

[What is the difference between a class and a type in Scala (and Java)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5031640/what-is-the-difference-between-a-class-and-a-type-in-scala-and-java)

https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html