# Companion object method not available to the companion class instance

Tags: scala, class, methods, companion-object

From the [official documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/book/domain-modeling-tools.html#abstract-classes:%7E:text=of%20its%20companion.-,Companion,-objects%20are%20used)

> Companion objects are used for methods and values that are not specific to instances of the companion class. For instance, in the following example the class Circle has a member named area which is specific to each instance, and its companion object has a method named calculateArea that’s (a) not specific to an instance, and **(b) is available to every instance**:

and the official example given is

```
import scala.math.*

class Circle(val radius: Double):
  def area: Double = Circle.calculateArea(radius)

object Circle:
  private def calculateArea(radius: Double): Double = Pi * pow(radius, 2.0)
```

I cannot get the point (b) to work:

```
import scala.math.*

class Circle(val radius: Double):
  def area: Double = Circle.calculateArea(radius)

object Circle:
  private def calculateArea(radius: Double): Double = Pi * pow(radius, 2.0)
@main def f() = {
  val t1 = Circle(1)
  t1.calculateArea(4) <-- compilation error calculateArea is not a member of Circle
}
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4):

Scala is not Java. You can't call class static methods on class instances as instance methods i.e. you can't call methods of companion object on class instances. A class and its companion object are different classes/types

[Class companion object vs. case class itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75286750/class-companion-object-vs-case-class-itself/)

> its companion object has a method named `calculateArea` that’s (a) not specific to an instance, and (b) is available to every instance:

(b) means just that private members of companion object (e.g. `calculateArea`) are accessible in the class and private members of the class are accessible in the companion object. Private members of a class and its companion object are not accessible outside the class and its companion object (e.g. in `@main`).